# Creating custom *.domain.com domains for sign-ups

Tags: java, apache, domain-name

I am curious as to how, for example Beanstalk and Server Density, create custom domains (e.g. custom.beanstalkapp.com, custom.serverdensity.com) for each sign-up. I would like to do something similar so that clients and their staff access the web-app at their own sub-domain. Each app either uses LDAP or our own native user storage depending on client choice and would share a common API.

Does each custom domain share the same web app code base?

Taking this further what if I wanted to allow a completely custom domain as you can get with bit.ly pro. I'd imagine in this case the customer would point the A record for their domain to our web servers and then we would have to programatically edit our Apache configuration to add a new virtual host for that domain?

In this application the API is written in Java (using Restlet) with the front-end written in GWT. The data layer is built in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a web server where you can programatically change the configuration notably for the virtual hosts.

This will most likely mean that you will want an embeddable server to have full control of what goes on instead of hacking on a stand-alone server.  That is the first step.  Do that first.

Comment: Does this mean using something like Jetty?

Comment: @Christopher, I have found Jetty to be very useful, but I do not know if it is easy to do what you ask for as I have not done something like that.  The jetty mailing lists are very helpful, I would suggest you have a look at the doucmentation and if stuck, ask on the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard dns and name based virtual hosts in apache to accomplish the subdomain bit.

Comment: and then parse the domain name in your code to serve the proper data for the requested domain